# Selenium: Partial text match when doing explicit wait

Tags: python, web-scraping

The page I am trying to scrape is https://www.toyota.com/dealers/#search&zipcode=01401

and I am iterating through the zipcodes.

For the rest of my code, if a dealer is found, it can extract that info and run to the next zipcode. However, I am struggling when no dealer is found.

I am trying to wait for the text "We found no dealers" ... to appear before trying the next iteration but it has another dynamic text following that line that I am not concerned with.

How do I need to rewrite

```py
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "operations_monitoring_tab_current_ct_fields_no_data"), "We found no dealers")
```

to not care about text following that?

Comment: I think more code, relevant html and perhaps url is required. Are you saying your partial match occurs twice and you want the second occurrence? Where is this iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Use the rest API and test the value in the numDealer field being > 0

```
import requests

for code in ['01401','03217']:
    r = requests.get('https://www.toyota.com/ToyotaSite/rest/dealerLocator/locateDealers?brandId=1&zipCode={}'.format(code)).json()
    numDealers = r['numDealer']
    if numDealers > 0:
        for dealer in r['dealers']:
            print(dealer)
```